# Installing latest version (5.62.1) wordpress edition failure

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am trying to install civiCRM for my wordpress website. I followed the instructions multiple times on how to install civicrm, but it ends in the same way. When I activate civicrm in the plugin menu on wordpress and hit the green install button, I get redirected to a page not found error (HTTP 500). I have tried older versions and same thing. I am currently hosting on Ionos if that matters.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem, but I reverted my Ionos PHP to 7.4 and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

We ran a CiviCRM/Wordpress install on Ionos for 10 years without issue--no technical issues with Ionos. Are you using one or two databases? We used two Mysql dbs which we created with PHPMyAdmin before installing WP.

BTW, last year we got fed up with Ionos's forced/charged PHP upgrades (and everything that entailed for CiviCRM/Wordpress) so switched to CiviCRM/Wordpress on AWS Lightsail--free for non-profits (see AWS credit available through TechSoup).

Comment: I would add that you do not have to be a nonprofit to get the $1,000 in AWS credits if you are a startup. Probably about everyone quals for the money! ;)